# Using Apex/VisualForce to pull data from Resource Planner

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am an intern who is relatively new to SalesForce with a computer science/programming background. I know that for many/most "reports" in SalesForce there is an option to export the data into an excel or .csv file, but I was given the task of trying to pull data from the SalesForce "Resource Planner" which has no apparent export function, and put the data into an Excel spreadsheet. The page looks as follows:
[image: The base page for "Resource Planner" in SalesForce]

I read that most of SalesForce uses apex code; I have a decent Java background and have read quite a few tutorials on apex and VisualForce, but I can't seem to find a way to get into this page and extract the data. I know this isn't the clearest question, but if anyone could provide some type of help on how to use Apex/VisualForce to get the data out of SalesForce and into Excel, or if this is even possible, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this is a 3th party tool that has been added to your salesforce instance (app exchange). It's probably a managed package with a custom data model. Can you access these objects ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know exactly what you mean. I have used SOQL in the Sandbox Developer console and I've been able to search and isolate the planners, but I don't know if there's anything I can do with that. I have figured out that it is FinancialForce Professional Service Automation that provides this specific "Resource Planner" (via google searches). I've tried to find the specific package in which this would be contained through a relatively extensive search of our Sandbox version of SalesForce, but have been unable to explicitly find anything called "Resource Planner" which I could post.